# Dropbox photo uploading

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller, dropbox-api

I am using dropbox api in my app. I have downloaded images from dropbox into applications document folder. Now I want to upload photos. If I used UIImagePicker then I cant upload it from document folder since it takes saved photo albums or camera. Is there any way to save images from image picker in document's directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implement the delegate method [`imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007069-CH3-SW8). Here's how you'd do it –

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);

    ...
    // Get filePath here
    ...

    [imageData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
}
```

There is another key `UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage` which might also be of interest for you.

Comment: I should use uiimagepickercontrollersourcetypecamera? And How can I test this on simulator

Comment: I have to save photos in document folder.In that case  I have to take images from somewhere. I have to use camera for this otherwise I have to save already saved images to document folder..?

Comment: No I meant use `PhotoLibrary` mode to test in the simulator since the camera is unavailable. But in the product it should be as you mentioned.